# OpenSSL encrypt in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, token

I'm encrypted the token I'm using in my system to pass through the URL, and it has always same last 2 character every trigger the encrypted token.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
function encrypt($string)
{
    $output = false;

    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'ExampleKey';
    $secret_iv = 'ExampleIv';

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    $output = base64_encode($output);

    return $key;
}
?>
```

the token result is always the same last 2 characters, here it is

```
eg #1
token=Z0ZkSmZhWjMzRUxTcCtxY2o1ZlFJdz09
eg #2
token=STE2b05oMVkwK3FIV0lhUkYyN0tmdz09
```

I just want to remove the "09" in the encryption or to be different.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should be returning `$output` from your function instead of `$key`

But since that was obviously a typo from posting here because of your different example output, the answer is not because of openssl, but because of the base64 encoding size. If your `$string` is more than 14 characters, then you'll get a different ending.

See this example: https://3v4l.org/eIMMY